# Why teammates appears differently in mini-maps?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

I played infected for the first time today.

I wasn't sure how the game should be played, I gave a particular attention on minimap.

I saw at least one "doubled" green triangles (teammate). I thought it was because he got infected...

Later I played a Team death match KC and I saw the same doubled triangle.

What does it mean ?

---

Edit

Here's a [screen shot of this video.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UCZfAs42q9M)

[image: screenshot]

Why the teammate pointed by the red arrow appears differently ?

Comment: uhhh I would have thought it was because he was speaking? going by the fact there is an open mic under the minimap..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon closer examination, this seems to indicate that a teammate just spawned.  In MW3, for a few seconds after spawning, teammates are immune to enemy UAV and similar killstreak rewards.  If you've ever used the recon drone you may notice that when players first spawn there is no red box, but then a few seconds pass and the red box appears.  If you watch that video starting at about 0:34 you'll see that player spawn, and then the addition hash marks around their arrow gradually fade.  This would seem to indicate that once the marks are gone, your ally is visible to enemy killstreaks.

Comment: What I found this video on youtube, I thought the same thing :-)

Comment: I meant `When I found...` :-)